# localStorage each and for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage

i retrieve the data from localStorage with each loop, but now i need a for loop, that makes the same thing.

So my each loop looks like :

```
var alleDaten = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("Deneme"));
 $.each(alleDaten, function(i,item){
     alert(item.id);
     alert(item.createdBy);
 });
```

i've tried this code, but it doesn't work:

```
      var alleDaten = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("Deneme"));
      for (i=0;i < alleDaten.length;i++) {
         var x= localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
         alert(x[i].id);
         alert(x[i].createdBy);
      }
```

Can you convert in a for loop? 
Thanks in advance

i've found the solution :

```
var alleDaten = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("Deneme"));
for (var i = 0; i < alleDaten.length; i++) {
    var x= alleDaten[i].id;
    var y= alleDaten[i].createdby;
    alert(x);
    alert(y);
  }
```

but thanks anyway

Comment: In the first bit of code you use the `$.parseJSON` function, is there a reason why you don't use this in your for loop?

Comment: i've used also in second code.

Comment: Inside the loop, should it be just `var x = alleDaten[i];`

Comment: And should the alerts be `alert(x.id);` and `alert(x.createdBy);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `in` like this:

```
var alleDaten = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("Deneme"));
for (key in alleDaten) {
   var x = alleDaten[key];
   alert(x.id);
   alert(x.createdBy);
}
```

Does that help?